# Bind TabItem to List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basic concept would be, when user presses start button and a new list comes back from worker thread, it'd be added to a "list of lists" than would be showed up in a newly created tabitem.
However I cannot seem to grab the datagrid on the newly created tabitem.....still could not figured out, FindName and whatever methods was tried

XAML

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabMain" Margin="8,63,10,10" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="grMain" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgResults" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFAAE8D5" ItemsSource="{Binding data}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding col1}" Width="150">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding col2}" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />

                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl >
```

CODE after getting the list

```
lstFinal.Add(e.Result as List<Col1Col2>);
TabItem newtab = new TabItem();
newtab.DataContext = lstFinal[lstFinal.Count - 1];


newtab.Header = txtMaterial.Text;
tabMain.Items.Add(newtab);
tabMain.SelectedIndex = tabMain.Items.Count - 1;
DataGrid dg = newtab.FindName("dgResults") as DataGrid;
dg.ItemsSource = lstFinal[lstFinal.Count - 1];
```

Comment: yes that is my problem dg is null (not found). list isfine, only dg is  the problem

Comment: When you post a question, then it is of utmost importance to describe what exactly is going wrong - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist. In your situation I would have tried to solve everything on ViewModel side, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx is a slightly old, but nonetheless solid article on MVVM that actively uses TabItems.

Comment: I am barely familiar with exact mechanics of `FindName` and its use with template, so I could only recommend you to try classic way of searching with `LogicalTreeHelper` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type. Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101411/find-children-of-a-user-control-in-a-tab-item.

Comment: @EugenePodskal, while I would normally agree with your sentiments, in this case, or any case where a question author says that they can't access a `DataTemplate` generated control, the solution is fairly obvious and straight forward and it is unnecessary to provide further information. However, your recommendation of using the `LogicalTreeHelper` was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused because you are trying to reference a control from within a `DataTemplate`. At run time, this template may have been applied to a large number of controls, so first you have to get the object that had the template applied and *then* you can access the control from the `DataTemplate`.

You can find out exactly how to do that by referring to the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. However, in short, this is how it's done (from the linked page):

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem 
// Note that the ListBox must have 
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem =
    (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);

// Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
MessageBox.Show("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: "
    + myTextBlock.Text);
```

The definition of the `FindVisualChild` method can also be found on the linked page, along with a description of the process.